# Getting "not talking to master and retries used up" Exception at DBCursor.hasNext()

Tags: java, mongodb

I am getting "not talking to master and retries used up" Exception at statement DBCursor.hasNext().

When I searched, got the solution as set the preference. Still i am getting the issue.

My code is as below:

```
public void sampleTest() throws Exception
    {   

MongoClient client = new MongoClient("192.168.20.117", 27017);

DB database = client.getDB("CLME2ECORE");

boolean auth = database.authenticate("tecnotree", ("tecnotree").toCharArray());


DBCollection collection = database.getCollection("RegistrationRequest");

collection.setReadPreference(ReadPreference.primary());

BasicDBObject andQuery = new BasicDBObject("serviceRequest.serviceRequestSubtype.masterCode","RETPOSTREG");
andQuery.append("serviceRequest.serviceRequestStatus.masterCode", "PYMTPEND");

BasicDBObject andFields = new BasicDBObject("serviceRequest.customer.profileDetails.basicDetails.customerCode",1);
andFields.append("_id", 0);

DBCursor dbCursor = collection.find(andQuery);
DBObject dbObject;

dbCursor.setReadPreference(ReadPreference.primary());

if(dbCursor.hasNext())
{
     dbObject = dbCursor.next();

     String value = dbObject.get("serviceRequest.customer.profileDetails.basicDetails.customerCode").toString();
}



client.close();
```

}

I am using maven dependencies as

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
    <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
    <version>2.13.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
 <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
 <artifactId>bson</artifactId>
 <version>2.13.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Please help to resolve this issue.

Comment: Is 192.168.20.117 a member of  a replicaSet? If so you should give an array of replicaSet members as the argument to MongoClient http://api.mongodb.com/java/2.10.1/com/mongodb/MongoClient.html

Comment: @hogan, Thanks it is working fine now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do these changes, then it will work.

1. Pass the complete replica set string while connecting to the mongodb, do not pass an individual server IP.
2. Change the readPreferance to PrimaryPrefferred, instead of Primary only.

Answer (score 0):

I met the exactly the same problem as you. I'm using java spring connect to a slave mongo database. The following code should be helpful.

```js
@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:param.properties")
public class MongoConfig {

    public @Bean MongoClientFactoryBean mongo() {

        MongoClientFactoryBean mongo = new MongoClientFactoryBean();
        mongo.setHost(mongoAddress);
        mongo.setPort(mongoPort);
        MongoClientOptions mco = new MongoClientOptions.Builder().readPreference(ReadPreference.secondaryPreferred()).build();

        mongo.setMongoClientOptions(mco);
        return mongo;
    }

    @Value("${mongo.address}")
    private String mongoAddress;

    @Value("${mongo.port}")
    private Integer mongoPort;
}
```

The key line is following:

```js
            MongoClientOptions mco = new MongoClientOptions.Builder().readPreference(ReadPreference.secondaryPreferred()).build();
```

Which indicate the mongo client as secondard perferred.